# Sorting PHP array based on different array

Tags: php

So I've searched for hours but no thread seems to get me to a working solution.

**My problem;**
I've got 2 arrays. 1 array with the user's roles. And one array with all roles with an specific order.

```
$roles = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22465
            [name] => Rank 1
            [position] => 24
            [color] => 16711680
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 59454
            [name] => Rank 2
            [position] => 15
            [color] => 15844367
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 62280
            [name] => Rank 3
            [position] => 2
            [color] => 65494
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 67139
            [name] => Rank 4
            [position] => 10
            [color] => 1146986
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 75372
            [name] => Rank 5
            [position] => 25
            [color] => 1146986
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 75373
            [name] => Rank 6
            [position] => 18
            [color] => 1146986
        )
    ...
)
```

And I have the user roles array:

```
$userdata = Array
(
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22465
            [1] => 59454
            [2] => 62280
            [3] => 67139
            [4] => 75372
            [5] => 75373
        )
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => irrelevant
        )

)
```

I want the user roles array to be sorted to the roles 'position' in the other array.
I think the bottleneck is in the part that the array has to be called with the subarray [roles][position] to get the order to work.

The result should be:

```
[0] => 75372
[1] => 22465
[2] => 75373
[3] => 59454
[4] => 67139
[5] => 62280
```

Could you please help me any further?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`array_multisort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort), possibly with some help from [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column) should be the way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// First, build a lookup table relating id directly to position
$ranks = [];
foreach($roles as $role) {
    $ranks[$role['id']] = $role['position'];
}

var_dump($ranks);

// Now sort the table using the lookup table we just produced
//
 usort($userdata['roles'], function($a, $b) use ($ranks){
        return $ranks[$b] <=> $ranks[$a];
 });

var_dump($userdata);
```

Content of `userdata` array after sorting

```
array (size=2)
  'roles' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => int 75372
      1 => int 22465
      2 => int 75373
      3 => int 59454
      4 => int 67139
      5 => int 62280
  'data' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'irrelevant' (length=10)
```